# Ehcache: Free up RMI port after use

Tags: java, ehcache

I am using Ehcache on tomcat server application. After my use, I am calling
`cacheManager.shutdown()`. However, next time when my code runs, without server restart, I get an error, `Port in use.`. How can I free up the port after ehcache use ?
Please note: My server will not be stopped, so shutdown hook is useless for me.

Comment: could you please add a stack trace when the port in use error happens ? I'm wondering how / when / if ehcache is trying to bind RMI. BTW, what's your ehcache version and configuration ?

Comment: My Ehcache version is 1.6beta (yeah quite old, cannot upgrade). I solved this problem, by doing manager.removeCache(..) and then shutdown

Comment: @AnthonyDahanne I realized that when I do `cacheManager.shutdown`, then only on the machine where this code runs, the port becomes free there only... `cache.removeAll()` is replicated to all servers, while `cacheManager.shutdown()` isnt... what would you suggest ?

Comment: well, just like you said, it's a pretty old version :-) . I guess it'd be worth it checking if there are any CacheManagerEventListener callbacks that could help you out :-/